# Google Earth 3D model web service

Tags: google-earth, collada

In Google Earth, I have a `<gx:Track>` which has a `<model>` element (https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#model). 
The model has a `<Link>` element in which the `<href>` defines the collada (dae) model to be used.

When working with files on my computer, I can manually set the `<href>` to a local path (eg c:\temp\model.dae") and the model displays correctly.

Now I want write a web service to return model.dae dynamically. I'm having trouble figuring what format google earth is expecting with regard to Content Type / Content Disposition / content.

I have tried `ContentType = "model/vnd.collada+xml"` and `Content-Disposition = "attachment; filename=""collada.dae"""` but Google Earth fails to load the model without any errors.

Have also tried `"Content-Disposition", "inline;"`

Please can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After a more digging around.... 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kml-support-server-side-scripting/Lh3xR2GTBc8

So, just need `.ContentType = "text/xml"` and `.ContentEncoding = Text.Encoding.UTF8`. No need to specify anything for `content-disposition`

Ah well, hope this is of use to someone else in the future.

Comment: One more twist.... need to include collada extension ".dae" somewhere in request, otherwise Google Earth won't recognize it. For example: http://myserver/collada.ashx?name=xyz.dae